# Mixing Objective C++and C++, function not returning value

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

I am trying to port some code I had written on Windows into a Mac application with Xcode and I've run into a really weird problem. My C++ function is no longer returning a value, I've used the debugger to confirm that the variable being returned does contain a value(inside the called function) but then my variable I'm assigning my function to is still NULL.

```
// calling the function
vec3* vs = getRandomizedPoints(NUM_POINTS, a, b);

// function being called
vec3* getRandomizedPoints(unsigned int numOfPoints, vec3 startRange, vec3 endRange)
{
    unsigned int i;
    vec3* ret = (vec3*)malloc(sizeof(vec3) * numOfPoints);

    srand(clock());

    for (i = 0; i < numOfPoints; ++i)
    {
        ret[i].x = randWithinRange(startRange.x, endRange.x);
        ret[i].y = randWithinRange(startRange.y, endRange.y);
        ret[i].z = randWithinRange(startRange.z, endRange.z);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

ret does contain a value when it is returned but in the calling code the vs variable is still NULL, can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see any mistake. Is this the exact code ? Are you sure you are accessing `vs` at later point of code ?

Comment: This is the exact code, and I wasn't accessing it at a later point in the code. Once I changed that the vs variable was populated outside of the function, however when I try to assign the function to my static vec3* vecs = NULL; it simply doesn't work and vecs is accessed later in code by a different file but assigning from vs to vecs simply doesn't work.

Comment: actually I just got this working by making the static variable a member of a class, why that works I have no idea??